# Add points (Lat-Lon) to a marmap plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I would like to plot a series of lat-lon points of a seal track, each coloured according to an attribute, on to a map that shows the bathymetry (100m contours) and coastline. I learnt how to create a map to show the bathymetry+coastline using marmap and ggplot2. The code is here:

```
dat <- getNOAA.bathy(-58,-62.5,43,46.0,res=0, keep=TRUE)
plot(dat,image=TRUE,bpal = list(c(min(dat), 0, "darkblue", "blue","lightblue"), c(0, max(dat), "gray90","gray10")),drawlabels=TRUE,deep=c(-500,200,0),shallow=c(-500,100,0),step=c(500,100,0),lwd=c(1,1,1),lty=c(1,1,1),land=TRUE)+
  scaleBathy(dat, deg=1.232, x="bottomleft", inset=5) #100km
```

This created a useful map. However, I am stalled over how to add the seal track on to this map.

I could do this in ggmap (using the code below) but I much prefer the marmap map

```
myLocation <- c(-62.5,43,-58,46)
seal_map2<-get_map(location=myLocation,maptype="watercolor",source="stamen",zoom=10)
ggmap(seal_map2)+
geom_point(data=sealtrack,aes(color=category),size=0.5)+
scale_color_gradientn(colours=rainbow(6), breaks=seq(1,6,by=1))
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with using the classical marmap map you created and adding your seal track with `points(sealtrack, col=some.color.vector[category])` ? Also take a look at pages 6-7 of `vignette("marmap-DataAnalysis")`. I believe this is exactly what you are looking for. Just replace the depth values used in the example to color the points by your `category` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the bathymetric info from marmap as a contour layer on your plot after "fortifying" it. Without your data it's difficult to make sure that it works (and the NOAA server is down for me right now):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(marmap)
dat <- getNOAA.bathy(-58,-62.5,43,46.0,res=0, keep=TRUE)
dat <- fortify(dat)
ggmap(seal_map2) +
   geom_contour(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
   geom_point(data=sealtrack,aes(color=category),size=0.5) +
   scale_color_gradientn(colours=rainbow(6), breaks=seq(1,6,by=1))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for gmap. I now just need to make this map as useful as the map from marmap.